# Are possibly outdated and damaging studies being taught in universities, and should I be worried?

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, career-path

As someone who is soon to be going to an online university for a degree in Psychology, I have been reading a lot of criticism on the academic field being inundated with "outdated" and click bait style studies being cited as solid fact with little ground to stand on. Some have even said the published studies were more for a paycheck than furthering the field.

Is this just a horrible misconception or does this field have a problem that still needs to be addressed? And as a new student, should I be worried?

Comment: What degree level are you going for? B.S./B.A., or M.S.? If it's the former, I wouldn't worry too much. The fundamentals of pretty much every discipline (with a few exceptions) haven't changed much, so concerns at the top of the discipline may be less relevant. For prospective, a lot of the things I learned in computer engineering as an undergrad were wildly out of date (i.e., stuff that hasn't been used in 20 years). What mattered were the *concepts* -- i.e., Ohm's Law -- which haven't changed since the beginning of the discipline.

Comment: Almost all studies are done for  a paycheck. Very few people do research for free (in any discipline).

Comment: This is not a misconception. It's good to be very sensitive to the weaknesses of a proposed discipline before your sunk cost becomes too great.

Comment: @tonysdg will be going through a bachelor/masters program, from there I will be pushing to get my doctorate.

Comment: @JeremyMiles well yes, I may have not worded that the best. What I meant was people backing papers and putting their name on it just for the purpose of selling books. Not because the study or the material was substantial. It's that kind of behavior I find troubling.

Comment: @JeremyMiles, within and without the ivory tower, there are **many** people that do unfunded research.

Comment: I would point out that you can either either be "outdated", focusing on older, more thoroughly vetted material and studies that have been confirmed in many ways and over multiple years, or you can focus on only the newest findings - some of which may turn out to be garbage, unreproducible, and not worthy of anyone's serious consideration. Education, to a first-order, is about becoming mature in the skills and understanding to be better able to tell the difference in what is junk and what genuinely teaches us something new and worthwhile.

Comment: A lot of disciplines are very outdated with regards to how they use other disciplines' tools.  Most major disciplines have some sort of reliance on computational methods, mathematical modeling, statistics, and often physics - but few practitioners are anywhere near up-to-date in their understanding of those fields.  As a student, you'll want to focus on the strong points an institution provides while avoiding its weaknesses.  If you take a class like "Statistics for Sociology", be warned that the course contents is just barely passable within that field, and often unacceptable outside of it.

Comment: This has always been the case. I was force-fed with the benefits of the Cultural Revolution in 1974, and that was already known to be bogus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some parts of the field of Psychology move very quickly. The pace of the field makes keeping course up to date difficult. For example, in 2013, there was a major update to the [DSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_and_Statistical_Manual_of_Mental_Disorders). Some classes were ignoring DSM-IV and teaching based on what eventually made it into DSM-5, others kept teaching based on DSM-IV. Some of these classes are still being taught on DSM-IV, despite the new guidelines since it takes time to get new text books and revamp lectures. The same thing happens with courses that look at pharmaceutical treatments and drug addiction. The fields move too quickly to keep up, and many teach based on a snapshot of the world.

As for cutting edge research, Psychology, like many fields has lots of great research and lots of questionable research. Not all Psychology programs get so far as to expose students to cutting edge research. Those that do, tend to try and teach students to read critically.

In summary, the point of a degree is to become a critical thinker. The fact that there are alternative theories is not something to worry about, but rather something to embrace.